# PLINQ O(n^2) while modifying basis list

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, plinq

Suppose I have this sequential function:

```
private void Process()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < Particles.Count; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < Particles.Count; j++)
      if (check(Particles[i], Particles[j])
      {
        Particle newParticle = Particle.Merge(Particles[i], Particles[j]);
        Particle p1 = Particles[i];
        Particle p2 = Particles[j];

        Particles.Remove(p1);
        Particles.Remove(p2);
        Particles.Add(newParticle);

        i = j = 0;
      }
}
```

So what does this do? It checks to see if two particles should be merged or not. If they should, a new particle is created, the originals are removed from the list, and the new particle is added to the list.

Then I did some lazy stuff by setting i and j to zero. In a single `for` loop, I can just `Particles.RemoveAt(i--)` and the loop will continue where it left off, but since here we have i and j it's a lot more complicated.

Anyway. This is another block of code which should be very easy to parallelise. The only problem is that I need to modify the collection I'm iterating over, regardless whether it's parallel or sequential.

If I use `foreach` instead of `for`, I get an exception saying the size of the collection has changed. If I use PLINQ:

```
private void Process()
{
  Particles.AsParallel.ForAll(p1 =>
  {
    Particles.ForEach(p2 =>
    {
      if (check(p1, p2)
      {
        Particle newParticle = Particle.Merge(p1, p2);

        Particles.Remove(p1);
        Particles.Remove(p2);
        Particles.Add(newParticle);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I get a LINQ exception.

Is there any way I can parallelise this n^2 operation and be able to change the contents of the list?

Comment: Your program is crashing because you're modifying the collection you're iterating over. Don't do that.

Comment: I perfectly aware why it's throwing an exception. My question was how to implement this with `AsParallel()` so that it /doesn't/ throw an exception.

Comment: For one, don't use `ForAll` and `ForEach`. Use `Select`.

Comment: You should try to avoid using `ForAll` when you have the possibility of a race condition or when you need to mutate the structure of a collection. A better solution would be to create, in parallel, a new list (cheap to do, you're working with references) and replace the old one.

Comment: If I ever get around to finishing it, you may interested in a recursive PLINQ N-Body solver I wrote. It handles collisions in the same exact way I described in my post below.

Comment: I am actually working on NBody at the moment, coincidentally...

Comment: What if `check(p1, p2) && check(p1, p3)`?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it this way:

```
from p1 in Particles.AsParallel()
    let collisions = from p2 in Particles
                     where p1 != p2
                     where check(p1, p2)
                     select p2
    select Particle.Merge(p1, collisions)
```

Where the second `Particle.Merge` acts on the list of collisions to generate a new Particle. You'll want some more logic in here than this, but that should give you an idea.

The basic idea is you want to non-destructively create a new copy of the list. Then do whatever modifications and replace the old list.

Some things you'll want to do are:

- Modify `Particle.Merge` to operate on a list: `Particle.Merge(Particle
  p, IEnumerable<Particle> collisions)`.
- Add some logic to prevent duplicates showing up in that list twice.